# How to find sum on basis of type and name key in ruby? (ruby array of hashes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How to find a sum on basis of type and name key in ruby? (ruby array of hashes)

```
eatables = [{type: "fruit", name: "apple", count: 2},
            {type: "vegetable", name: "pumpkin", count: 3},
            {type: 'fruit', name: 'apple', count: 1},
            {type: "vegetable", name: "pumpkin", count: 2}]
```

Desired Output

```
[{type: "fruit", name: "apple", count: 3},
 {type: "vegetable", name: "pumpkin", count: 5}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eatables.group_by { |h| h.slice(:name, :type) }
        .map { |key, grouped| key.merge(count: grouped.sum{ |h| h[:count] }) }
```

The first operation splits the array into groups based on the name and type.

```
{{:name=>"apple", :type=>"fruit"}=>[{:type=>"fruit", :name=>"apple", :count=>2}, {:type=>"fruit", :name=>"apple", :count=>1}], {:name=>"pumpkin", :type=>"vegetable"}=>[{:type=>"vegetable", :name=>"pumpkin", :count=>3}, {:type=>"vegetable", :name=>"pumpkin", :count=>2}]}
```

We then map across that hash and return an array of hashes with the type, name, and sum which outputs:

```
=> [{:name=>"apple", :type=>"fruit", :count=>3}, {:name=>"pumpkin", :type=>"vegetable", :count=>5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem can be solved with a [reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

```
output = eatables.reduce({}) do |hsh, current|
             if hsh.has_key?(current[:type]+current[:name])
                 hsh[current[:type]+current[:name]][:count] += current[:count]
             else 
                hsh[current[:type]+current[:name]] = current
             end
             hsh
         end.values
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for response but you not checked :name key

Comment: @alavnishubham I've updated the code to check the `:name` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
eatables.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, item|
  h[item.slice(:type, :name)] += item[:count]
  h
}.map { |k, v|
  {**k, count: v}
}
```

Comment: A less "golfy" version would be `eatables.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h, memo| h[item.slice(:type, :name)] += item[:count] }.map {|k,v| k.merge(count: v) }`. `each_with_object` is less awkward when you're modifying a hash on each iteration.

Comment: @max, I think you meant `eatables.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h, memo| memo[h.slice(:type, :name)] += h[:count] }.map...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland oops, yeah that looks right.